# UnicodeDecodeError: 'gbk' codec can't decode bytes

Tags: python, unicode, python-3.x, decode, pickle

I'm trying to load an object (of a custom class Area) from a file using pickler.  I'm using python 3.1.

The file was made with `pickle.dump(area, f)`

I get the following error, and I would like help trying to understand and fix it.

`File "editIO.py", line 12, in load
    area = pickle.load(f)`

`File "C:\Python31\lib\pickle.py", line 1356, in load
    encoding=encoding, errors=errors).load()`

UnicodeDecodeError: 'gbk' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: illegal multibyte sequence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to say without you showing your code, but it looks like you opened the file in text mode with a "gbk" encoding. It should probably be opened in binary mode. If that doesn't happen, make a small code example that fails, and paste it in here.

Comment: Thank you. It seems I was saving my files in binary mode with `open(file, wb)` and wasn't also opening them in binary mode.